# Why didn't the crew of the Endurance experience undertow from the massive waves on Miller's planet?

Tags: interstellar

When the crew lands on Miller's planet and notices the giant wave approaching, it seemed odd to me that there would be a lack of current pulling towards the wave.  The giant waves would command a tremendous amount of energy, so I feel like even trying to stand up before the massive wave hits would be impossible.

Comment: One question per... question, please.

Comment: Physicist Kip Thorne says in *The Science of Interstellar* that the waves are meant to be [tidal bores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_bore) caused by a slight back-and-forth rocking of the planet which causes it to deviate very slightly from being perfectly [tidally locked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) with the black hole. It's possible that tidal bores, being more isolated than an ordinary wave train with a series of many crests, don't behave the same way as wave trains in terms of the current that precedes the crest, but I can't find any info one way or another on this.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Make this an answer, friend!

Comment: No answer on this??